# CQRS Design Pattern - How to copy and transform data from SQL Command DB to NoSQL Query DB?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, cqrs

I'm fairly new to the Azure game but below are the options that (I think) could potentially work:

1. Logic App with an SQL Connector; which then fires an event which calls an Azure Function
2. Event Grid fires off an event calling an Azure Function; skips the Logic App
3. Azure Function with a timer trigger since there is no Azure SQL trigger; don't like this one but would get the job done

I'm sure there are other options that are available that I'm not aware of given the sheer size of Azure.

Is there a best practice given by Microsoft given this design pattern? Is it a matter of experience with a given Azure service? Maybe a combination of both? I'm open to any suggestions or advice.

[Note that using a read only Azure SQL database is not an option. Might have made life easier though...]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Binding with Azure Functions too, which is current in preview:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-sql-extension

My recommendation would be to create a CommandHandler which will perform both operations:

NewCustomerCommand

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email

NewCustomerCommandHandler

- DomainServices.SQLInsert
- DomainServices.NoSQLInsert

PS: You could use different Handlers for SQL / NoSQL but there would be a chance they will be in different states. This way, either both commit or rollback both operations